# Multiple plot with ggplot2: controlling the scale of each plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following type of data (inside a data.frame `df`):

```
x     A      B      C
1    100    1.2    1.3
2    90     1.1    0.9
```

I want to have a multiple bar plot of the columns `A`, `B`, `C` of `df`, so I run the following:

```
tmp <- cbind(df$x, melt(df[,-1]))
names(tmp) <- c("x", "variable", "value")
ggplot(tmp, aes(x,value)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity" ) + facet_grid(variable~.)
```

And it works fine, except for the fact that the values in the column `A` are much higher than for the rest, and the scales are not adapting.
Could somebody give me a hint on own to adjust the scale in each plot?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In the future, please include the `library` statements required for your code to run and use `dput` or a more easily reproducible representation of your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add `scales='free_y'` to `facet_grid` as documented in `?facet_grid`...

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

df <- read.data('clipboard', header=TRUE)

tmp <- cbind(df$x, melt(df[, -1]))
names(tmp) <- c("x", "variable", "value")

ggplot(tmp, aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity" ) + 
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales='free_y')
```

Comment: I've tried your answer, but i get this: `Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) : 
  argument "env" is missing, with no default`

Comment: Here is the correct answer, as Justin stated at the beginning: ggplot(tmp, aes(x,value)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity" ) + facet_grid(variable~., scales='free_y')